# Singular form of the biblical magi

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, grammatical-number

I was working on a crossword puzzle with the clue *bearer of gold, frankincense, or myrrh*. I immediately thought that the answer is obviously either "magi" or "wise man," but then realized that the puzzle called for a 5 letter word so neither fit. Eventually I figured out that magi is a plural Latin word, so its singular form would be "magus" which was the correct answer.

Is it normal to use the word "magus" in informal, or even formal, English? I've *never* seen it before. I have however often seen magi used as a singular noun.

Comment: The English word (derived from *magus)* is *mage,* of which *magi* is an alternate plural, *mages* being more common.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both “magus” and “magi” are attested in dictionaries. For example, in the *New Oxford American Dictionary*:

> magus (pl. magi)
>   a member of a priestly
>   caste of ancient Persia. (See also Magi.)
>   • a sorcerer.
>
> magi: plural form of magus .

“Magi”, with a capital M, is only used in the plural:

> Magi (the Magi)
>
> the “wise men” from the East who
>   brought gifts to the infant Jesus
>   (Matt. 2:1), said in later tradition
>   to be kings named Caspar, Melchior,
>   and Balthasar who brought gifts of
>   gold, frankincense, and myrrh.

So, the most common use (those specific Magi) only exists in the plural, though the singular of the common noun exists.